# Как убрать одну из прокруток?

Tags: html, css

ибо сейчас две прокрутки
смотрится странно

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
*::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
    background-color: #593d91;
  padding: 40px;
}

.table__wrap {
    overflow: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.table__wrap table {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.table__wrap tbody {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.table__wrap tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.table__wrap tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.table__wrap tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.table__wrap tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.table__wrap th,
.table__wrap td {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.table__wrap th {
    font-size: 43px;
}

.table__wrap td {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "ToyotaTypeBook";
}

.table__wrap thead tr th:first-child,
.table__wrap thead tr td:first-child,
.table__wrap tbody tr th:first-child,
.table__wrap tbody tr td:first-child {
    padding-left: 120px;
}

.table__wrap thead th:first-child,
.table__wrap thead td:first-child,
.table__wrap tbody th:first-child,
.table__wrap tbody td:first-child {
    max-width: 460px;
    min-width: 250px;
}

.table__wrap thead th:nth-child(2),
.table__wrap thead td:nth-child(2),
.table__wrap tbody th:nth-child(2),
.table__wrap tbody td:nth-child(2) {
    max-width: 270px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.table__wrap thead th:nth-child(3),
.table__wrap thead td:nth-child(3),
.table__wrap tbody th:nth-child(3),
.table__wrap tbody td:nth-child(3) {
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 250px;
}

.table__wrap thead th:nth-child(4),
.table__wrap thead td:nth-child(4),
.table__wrap tbody th:nth-child(4),
.table__wrap tbody td:nth-child(4) {
    max-width: 445px;
    min-width: 310px;
}

.table__wrap thead th:nth-child(5),
.table__wrap thead td:nth-child(5),
.table__wrap tbody th:nth-child(5),
.table__wrap tbody td:nth-child(5) {
    max-width: 250px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.table__wrap thead th:nth-child(6),
.table__wrap thead td:nth-child(6),
.table__wrap tbody th:nth-child(6),
.table__wrap tbody td:nth-child(6) {
    max-width: 270px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.table__wrap tbody tr td:nth-child(5),
.table__wrap tbody tr td:nth-child(6) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="table">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="table__wrap">   
            <table> 
                <thead> 
                    <tr>    
                        <th>Дата</th>
                        <th>Начало</th>
                        <th>Имя</th>
                        <th>Фамилия</th>
                        <th>Поменять</th>
                        <th>Удалить</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                        <td>25/11/21</td>
                        <td>10:15</td>
                        <td>Константин</td>
                        <td>Іванов</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: сделать для body полный overflow: hidden (а не только overflow-x)

Comment: но проблема в том, что и то, и то мне нужно

Comment: Тогда не очень понятен смысл вопроса. Если и та, и другая прокрутка нужны, зачем что-то убирать?

Comment: нюанс в том, что таблица должна пальцем прокручиваться вниз